# extracting a specific object from each element of a list in R

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list made of different numeric vectors of different length, and I'd like to know if you have any suggestion about how to extract the object with the same index (e.g., the third object of each element)

Imagine I have something like this:

```
States<-list(Italy=rbinom(5,4,0.5),Spain=rnorm(12,6,1),Greece=sample(1:14, 6))
> States
$Italy
[1] 2 2 1 4 2

$Spain
 [1] 5.403135 5.616146 7.224063 5.602878 6.738619 6.732706 7.636093 5.917246 5.901094
[10] 5.818594 7.420575 5.545782

$Greece
[1]  8  9  3 11  4 14
```

How can I get a numeric vector with the first object of each element that would be a vector like:

```
[1] 2 5.403135 8
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `lapply` or `sapply`, which will both eventually get you to the same result:

For `lapply`:

```
> lapply(States,function(x)x[1])
$Italy
[1] 2

$Spain
[1] 6.694136

$Greece
[1] 10
> unlist(lapply(States,function(x)x[1]), use.names=FALSE)
[1]  2.000000  6.694136 10.000000
```

For `sapply`:

```
> sapply(States,function(x)x[1])
    Italy     Spain    Greece 
 2.000000  6.694136 10.000000
> as.vector(sapply(States,function(x)x[1]))
[1]  2.000000  6.694136 10.000000
```

Comment: Yes, or even just `sapply(States, \`[\`, 1)`.